# Filter 1 column and return all associated records in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 18 columns....column 15 (o) is a list of accessories and column 5 (e) is the serial number tied to the accessory. I am trying to filter by accessory and return all of the accessories for the machine.

May be better to try and illustrate

```
column 15       Column 5
ACD             123456
ASR             123456
ACD             456789
AOM             456789
ER2             678901
```

If I filter column 15 for ACD I would like 4 rows returned the 2 for 123456 and the 2 for 456789.

This is so I can see what other accessory(ies) is/are on the machine in addition to the one I am looking for to see if it is a good fit for my need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new column that checks if each row shares the Serial Number with the Accessory you're looking for using COUNTIFS. Taking into account that you have accessories in the Column A and Serial Numbers in Column E, the formula would look like that for cell row 4:

```
COUNTIFS($E$4:$E$8,E4,$A$4:$A$8,$E$1)
```

- In Cell E1 is where you write the accessory you're looking for.
- I create Column F where the formula is applied.

See screenshot:

[image]